# How to correctly highlight cursor line in VIM?

Tags: vim

VIM can be configured to highlight current line via `:hi cursorline guibg=green` and `set cursorline` commands. But if I enable tabs display via:

```
:hi specialkey guifg=grey guibg=grey
:set listchars="tab"
:set list
```

Cursor line highlight will corrupt tabs display:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/239055/vim_cursorline_bug.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/239055/vim_cursorline_bug.png)

Any hints how i can avoid corruption so may tabs are highlighted with one color and cursor line is highlighted with another color without any `^I` displayed at intersection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `listchars` without the quotes:

```
:set listchars=tab:>-
```

This shows the tab as `>-------` instead of `^I`, which I think is what you were asking. When the cursor is on the line with the tab, the whole line is displayed in the `cursorline` colour.

It appears that the `cursorline` colour takes precedence over the `specialkey` colour, which is consistent with your screenshot.

Comment: Maybe it's somehow possible to use space character for displaying tabs in different color? syntax is `tab:xy`, but how to specify space for `x` and `y`? Maybe some escape notation?

Comment: Ah, i found this out:
`:set listchars=tab\ \ ,`
You can edit your answer for further search.